# Sharing Realm Between Users

Tags: realm

I am trying to implement Realm in my Android app.

I want to get all UserDetails Model Records which are registered in Realm Object Server for that I need to implement shared realm.

After searching a lot I came to know I can do by PermissionOffer and PermissionOfferResponse.

Now I am able to get token succesfully.
I was stuck in this step:

```
Send the token to another user Sharing Realm Between Users.
    1.Send the token to another user via any method.
```

Which method i need to use to send token to other user?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8XbU.png)

Comment: What step are you stuck in? What tutorial are you using? Do you have a specific problem, or are looking for help on what to do next?

Comment: I am able to get token successfully using PermissionOffer but how can i send this token to another user.

Comment: I am following this document https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've come across the part of the guide they consider out-of-scope for their product. It seems Realm expect you to be able to communicate a token to another user to establish the trust between the two users.

Commonly you either setup a server which handles passing tokens between users (ironic given I think that's what I think Realm say they do after you've setup the token), or you setup a peer-to-peer communication.

The peer-to-peer can be done in many ways, a simple bluetooth communication, encode the token into a URL and share over WhatsApp, use NFC to tap two phones together.

This part is arguably quite fun given the amount of flexibility you have (albiet understandable annoying given you'd assume Realm would support this step (which it might if you look at the docs). Google around and come up with a way of communicating a token, hope you have fun :)

Comment: We do realize that we don't offer to much in terms of how to share the token, the original design was to allow the developer to choose the mechanism that is most appropriate for their apps, such as email or SMS. However, we will be working to improve this where you could use a Realm to share it.

Comment: @AdamFish Oh I don't think you should xD My opinion is that if they cannot understand this part then maybe they shouldn't be developing a live network product, but oh well.